# Implementing a commandButton that returns to the previous page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

What I want to do is implement a JSF page that will return to the prior page once it is done.  This is with @RequestScoped beans.

The original page called **viewDocument.xhtml** has this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="ID" value="#{viewDocument.id}" />
</f:metadata>

 (bunch of stuff)

<h:link outcome="editThingy" value="Edit Thingy">
    <f:param name="ID" value="#{viewDocument.doc.id}" />
    <f:param name="Return" value="viewDocument" />
</h:link>
```

The target page **editThingy.xhtml** has its own backing bean, and looks like this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="ID" value="#{editThingy.id}" />
    <f:viewParam name="Return" value="#{editThingy.navReturn}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:form>

   (bunch of stuff)

   <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{editThingy.save}" >
      <f:param name="ID" value="#{editThingy.id}" />
   </p:commandButton>
   <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{editThingy.navReturn}" >
       <f:param name="ID" value="#{editThingy.id}" />
   </p:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

The idea is that both buttons (cancel or save) would return to the page indicated by the **Return** request parameter, with the new page getting the ID request parameter so it pulls up the same record that **EditThingy** worked on.

BZZZT!  The **p:commandButton** does a POST and not a GET, so it can't use **f:param**. However if I try to use **p:button** there is no attribute to call the backing bean!

Is there any way to implement what I want?

Comment: Have you tried with commandLink, it supports f:param or f:setPropertyActionListener for the commandButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:param>` should work just fine. You only need to retain the `Return` parameter for subsequent requests as well, exactly as you did for the `ID` parameter, otherwise it's lost during processing the form submit because your bean is request scoped instead of view scoped.

Thus so,

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{editThingy.save}" >
    <f:param name="ID" value="#{editThingy.id}" />
    <f:param name="Return" value="#{editThingy.navReturn} " />
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{editThingy.cancel}" >
    <f:param name="ID" value="#{editThingy.id}" />
    <f:param name="Return" value="#{editThingy.navReturn} " />
</p:commandButton>
```

with

```
public String save() { 
    // ...
    return navReturn;
}

public String cancel() { 
    return navReturn;
}
```

---

**Update**: based on the comments, the functional requirement has now become more clear. The cancel button can also be done as follows, assuming that you don't need to invoke a backing bean action method at all on cancel:

```
<p:button value="Cancel" outcome="#{editThingy.navReturn}" >
    <f:param name="ID" value="#{editThingy.id}" />
</p:button>
```

The save button can return the following:

```
return navReturn + "?id=" + id + "&faces-redirect=true";
```

Comment: It still isn't working for me.  I get the correct navigation: the "navReturn" sends me to the right page but the view parameters in the target page are never called.  The browser shows the URL with "editThingy.xhtml?ID=11&Return=viewDoc" which is what I would expect.  Any idea of what to try next?

Comment: Oh, you want something like `return navReturn + "?id=" + id + "&faces-redirect=true";`?

Comment: OK that worked.   I think this is really a hole in the JSF specification.   Redirect should be supported via tag attributes or API calls.  This business of concocting URLs with a secret parameter in the backing bean looks like poor coding practice.    Thanks for the millionth time.

Comment: As to the tag, there's a `<redirect>` for XML navigation cases. As to API call, there's an `ExternalContext#redirect()`.